# How to have both arch=amd64 and trusted=yes in sources.list of apt package manager?

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic, aptitude, localrepository

### What do I want to do?

You can have
  `deb [trusted=yes] http://pathtoserver/ubuntu bionic main`
`deb [arch=amd64] http://pathtoserver/ubuntu bionic main`

in sources.list separately.

Is there a way I can do
`deb [trusted=yes, arch=amd64] http://pathtoserver/ubuntu bionic main` or something like that where I can have only amd64 as options and trusted should be yes.
in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic.

---

### Error

If I use the following deb line
`deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] http://pathtoserver/ubuntu bionic main`

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Trusted regarding source
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

---

This is an airgapped system and I have mirrored the ubuntu repository for offline purpose.

Comment: According to https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/sources.list.5.en.html you only need to separate the options with spaces.  "options is always optional and needs to be surrounded by square brackets. It can consist of multiple settings in the form setting=value. Multiple settings are separated by spaces."

Comment: I get the following an error. I'm updating it now.

Comment: What kind of deb line did you use then?

Comment: amd64 earlier and now

Comment: Check the rest of the file and subfolders for conflicting content.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you saw thanks to [@Terrance's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212851/how-to-have-both-arch-amd64-and-trusted-yes-in-sources-list-of-apt-package-manag#comment2037522_1212851), you need to put the option like this : `[trusted=yes arch=amd64]` (in no particular order).

**Regarding your second error**, it would be because you have another entry that uses the same URL (http://pathtoserver/ubuntu) but does not have the `[trusted=yes]`.

For example, if you have one entry for *Releases* and one entry for *Sources*, they **both** need to have the `[trusted=yes]`.